# How to be notified when onPictureTaken() has been executed and has returned?

Tags: android, android-camera

I have a class variable `photoPath` which is initialized to null.

```
private static string photoPath = null;
```

Then inside the body of `onPictureTaken`, this variable is assigned a certain String value.

```
final PictureCallback pictureCallback = new PictureCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onPictureTaken() of Camera.PictureCallback called.");// check
        ...
        photoPath = aValidPathString;
        ...
    }
}
```

Then in the click listener of a button, I have called the `Camera.takePicture()` method. After that, I have logged out the value of `photoPath`. **This value of `photoPath` turns out to be `null` in the output; and `onPictureTaken() of Camera.PictureCallback called.` is never printed in the output. THIS means that *onPictureTaken()* is NOT called at the time I log out the value of `photoPath`.**

So I want to know when `onPictureTaken()` has returned, so that I can be sure that `onPictureTaken()` has been executed, and I log out the value of `photoPath` at that point. **How do I do that?**

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onClick() of View.OnClickListener called.");// check

        camera.takePicture(null, null, pictureCallback);

                /*while(photoPath==null) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "PHOTO_NAME is null at the moment.");/*
                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Waiting for half a second.");
                        }
                    }, 500);*
                }*/

        Log.i(TAG, photoPath);// check
    }
}
```

Comment: `takePicture()` is asynchronous. Work will not even begin on taking the picture until after `onClick()` returns, AFAIK. Move your code that needs the path to `onPictureTaken()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you, I am doing that. But did you downvote my question? If so, could you please tell me the reason?

Comment: "But did you downvote my question?" -- no, I did not.

Comment: Thank you, and thank you, the solution solved my problem. But AFAIK, Synchronous means a task starts only when another task ends; in other words, the execution of the second task is dependent on the first. And @CommonsWare Asynchronous means the execution of the second task DOES NOT depend on the first one; both the tasks could be executing at the same time, in different threads. So if `takePicture()` is asynchronous, should it start executing (parallel to `onClick()`) regardless of where `onClick()` is in its execution?

Comment: Here, by asynchronous, I mean that `takePicture()` returns immediately, without having taken the picture. And, since `onPictureTaken()` is to be called on the main application thread, even if `takePicture()` starts its work, you cannot be called with `onPictureTaken()` until sometime after `onClick()` returns, since your `onClick()` code is *also* running on the main application thread.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you very much. If you have time, could you tell me how you know that `onPictureTaken()` will be called on main thread, since the [reference doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.PictureCallback.html#onPictureTaken(byte[]) doesn't mention that.

Comment: I have spent lots of time with `onPictureTaken()`. :-) But, yes, that should be documented.

Comment: @CommonsWare Then I am taking your work. Thank you. =)

Comment: I see the android-camera-2 tag here, but your code is about the older, deprecated Camera class... editing the post to remove the misleading tag (please ping me if it was me the one who missed the camera2 part on your code). Also, if you found a solution consider sharing it as an answer under your post :)

Answer (score 0):

Just wait to recieve the callback `onCaptureCompleted` from your pictureCallback:

```
 private CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback pictureCallback = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onCaptureCompleted(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session,
                                       @NonNull CaptureRequest request,
                                       @NonNull TotalCaptureResult result) {

            // your picture has been taken
    };
```